# String method to get unknown value that matches regex from string

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java is there a way to extract the value of an unknown subset of a string via a regex. For example in the following string "hello world 1234" I want to be able to extract the value 1234 via the regex [0-9]*. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - put the bit that you want into a group in the regex.

There's a sort of tutorial [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html) or find "capturing the string that matched a pattern" in [this longer page](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/java-regular-expressions-in-java.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy with provided API:

- you generate your regexp pattern by `Pattern p = Pattern.compiler("regexp")`
- you try to match the pattern with the string you need: `Matcher m = p.matches(string)`
- lastly you iterate over groups captured

  `for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); ++i)
     System.out.println(m.group(i));`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can always check the 'official' tutorial regarding REGEX: [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/).